# How to enable HTML based streaming on nginx?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, nginx, streaming

I have developed an application in React with SSR rendering and used **renderToNodeStream** to have better TTFB and FCP. On my local machine, I am serving through Node server where streaming is working as expected. But on production, Request is served by the combination of servers as follows

Akamai (DNS resolved here and then it calls to load balancer) ----->
 nginx ----> node server.

The issue I am facing on the production environment is streaming is not working as we are getting the complete response on the client(browser).

I am assuming the issue must be at nginx level.